# In Haskell, how to provide the correct kind of number for this function?

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner with Haskell, trying out GPipe.

The following code runs fine:

```
shader <- compileShader $ do
  primitiveStream <- toPrimitiveStream id
  let transPrims = fmap
        (\(pos,col) -> (perspective (pi/3) 1 1 100 !* pos, col)) 
        primitiveStream
  fragmentStream <- rasterize
        (const (FrontAndBack, ViewPort (V2 0 0) (V2 500 500), DepthRange 0 1))
        transPrims
  drawContextColor (const (ContextColorOption NoBlending (V3 True True True)))
                   fragmentStream
```

However, I have 2 variables windowWidth and windowHeight (both of type Int), and when I try to do this:

```
shader <- compileShader $ do
  primitiveStream <- toPrimitiveStream id
  let transPrims = fmap
        (\(pos,col)
         -> (perspective (pi/3) (windowWidth/windowHeight) 1 100 !* pos, col))
        primitiveStream
  fragmentStream <- rasterize
        (const (FrontAndBack, ViewPort (V2 0 0) (V2 500 500), DepthRange 0 1))
        transPrims
  drawContextColor (const (ContextColorOption NoBlending (V3 True True True)))
                   fragmentStream
```

I get a compile error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘S V Float’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: Shader
                       os
                       (ContextFormat RGBFloat ())
                       (PrimitiveArray Triangles (B4 Float, B3 Float))

                       (PrimitiveStream Triangles (V4 Int, V3 VFloat))
        Actual type: Shader
                       os
                       (ContextFormat RGBFloat ())
                       (PrimitiveArray Triangles (B4 Float, B3 Float))
                       (PrimitiveStream Triangles (VertexFormat (B4 Float, B3 Float)))
```

Thinking it perhaps wants a float, I do `(toFloat $ windowWidth/windowHeight)`:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Float’ with ‘S V Float’
      Expected type: VFloat
```

How do I get a VFloat?

Comment: `(windowWidth :: Int) / (windowHeight :: Int)` is a type error: you can't use `(/)` with `Int`. That's not the error being reported, but it is an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`VFloat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GPipe-2.1.8/docs/Graphics-GPipe-Expr.html#t:VFloat) is a synonym for `S V Float`. [Several lines above the `VFloat` entry](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GPipe-2.1.8/docs/Graphics-GPipe-Expr.html), the *GPipe* documentation explains that:

> The type `S x a` is an opaque type that represents a value of type `a` in a shader stage `x`, eg `S F Float` means a floating point value in a fragment stream.

It also tells us, through the list of instances just below, that there are instances of both `Num` and `Fractional` for `S whatever Float`. The  the `Num` instance explains why you could pass the literal `1` as an `S V Float` argument. That also means you can use [`fromIntegral`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to create `S V Float` values, so the following should do the trick:

```
fromIntegral windowWidth / fromIntegral windowHeight
```

(I have used that rather than simply `fromIntegral (windowWidth / windowHeight)` because, as crockeea points out, you can't use `(/)` with `Int`s, as `Int` has no `Fractional` instance.)

Comment: Aaand.... the triangle isn't stretched anymore! But then what does toFloat do? The documentation says "Convert to a floating point number.". Is that different from `S V Float`?

Comment: @user1582024 [1/2] `toFloat :: Convert a => a -> ConvertFloat a` is a method of the `Convert` class, while `ConvertFloat` is an associated type family of that class, which means that for every `a` type with a `Convert` instance there is a corresponding `ConvertFloat a` type. Looking at the instances shows that `toFloat` can be used to convert, for instance, an `Int` to a `Float` (in which case it is equivalent to `fromIntegral`) or a `S V Int` to a `S V Float`.

Comment: @user1582024 [2/2] I'm not entirely sure about when you'd need to use `toFloat` rather than `fromIntegral`, though if nothing else it does make the conversions within GPipe's DSL look more uniform. The *Working with lifted S-values* section of [this tutorial](http://tobbebex.blogspot.com.br/2015/10/gpu-programming-in-haskell-using-gpipe.html), which I found through the GitHub readme of the package, has a few more words on the motivation behind `Convert` and similar classes.

Answer (score 2):

`fromIntegral` will indeed convert an integral to a `S V Float`, but will do it at time of compilation of the shader. If you want it to be able to dynamically use the current window width and height at time of rendering each frame, you need to pass it in through a uniform in the shader environment (which then converts `Float`s to `S V Float`s and `Int`s to `S V Int`s).

Then you will either convert the window width to `Float` using `fromIntegral` before sending it into the GPU world of `S`-values, or use `toFloat` on the `S V Int` (which isn't an `Integral` and hence doesn't have `fromIntegral`)

You can read more about uniforms in GPipe in [part 3 of the tutorial](http://tobbebex.blogspot.se/2015/10/gpu-programming-in-haskell-using-gpipe.html)